# 60's short story set after a nuclear apocalypse, survivor is allowed out for a few minutes and climbs a hill to search for life signs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Post nuclear apocalypse the first person is allowed out above ground but wearing a suit and only for few minutes.

The oldest person is chosen... he wants to see if there is any sign of life on the other side of the hill but as he approaches the top his safe time is running out...

It was part of a 60's anthology.

Comment: You can check out the [guide to writing a good story-identification question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for more suggestions on details to add.  And welcome to SF&F!

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the 1960s anthology source, this reminds me very strongly of a "cleaning" segment from Hugh Howie's *Wool*.  That book (a collection of connected short stories, followed by two novel length sequels), however, came out in the 2000s.

A "cleaning" is a form of punishment for certain actions or thoughts, or a means of sanctioned suicide in the Silo -- a thousand foot deep underground shelter against a nano-plague, reinforced by drugs in the drinking water that induce forgetfulness and a network of IT departments that prevent any Silo from knowing about others.  In one of the "cleanings", instead of cleaning the above-ground sensors in a protective suit that lasts close to an hour, a character chooses to climb a hill toward the distant skeleton of a city -- and what she finds and how she survives are pivotal to the longer plot.